# LINQ-to-NHibernate Filter IQueryable by Composite Field - "Could not resolve property" error

Tags: linq-to-nhibernate

Quick background - I have a form that offers a handful of optional options to users and a search method on my service that accepts all those fields and attaches the necessary Where() conditions on the master IQueryable list.

One of those filters is a list of strings that must be compared to a combination of three different fields in the IQueryable.  here's the code throwing the "*could not resolve property*" error:

```
var searchResults = _transactionHeaders.Retrieve();
if (subgroups.Any())
    searchResults = searchResults.Where(s => subgroups.Contains(s.CustomerType + s.RusNumber + s.GroupNumber));

return searchResults.ToList()
```

I've read a few posts that suggest an alias needs to be created for any properties not directly mapped in the NHibernate mapping.  I'm not quite sure that is the solution to my problem.

Suggestions? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried altering my query approach to building dynamic queries (http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/19/nhibernate-queries-examples.aspx), but was unable to get that working either.

Hoping a calculated property would work, I tried a quick hack to join these 3 fields together:

public virtual string SubgroupCode { 
    get{ { return CustomerType + RusNumber + GroupNumber; } }}

then I changed my where clause to:

if (subgroups.Any())
            searchResults = searchResults.Where(s => subgroups.Contains(SubgroupCode));

Unfortunately, same "could not resolve property" error.

Answer (score 0):

Linq2Nhibernate can't understand a `.Contains` method call to.  You'll have to change your query so it's compatible with linq2nhibernate.